# Review: reusable safe_bool implementation

Tags: c++

Trying to find a "simple to use" safe_bool idiom/implementation, I've ended up with my own.

**Q: Is this implementation correct?**

```
template <typename T>
class safe_bool 
{
protected:
   typedef void (safe_bool::*bool_type)() const;
   bool_type to_bool_type(bool b) const 
     { return b ? &safe_bool<T>::safe_bool_true : 0; }

private:
   void safe_bool_true() const {}

private:
   bool operator ==(safe_bool<T> const & rhs);
   bool operator !=(safe_bool<T> const & rhs);
};
```

to be used like this:

```
struct A : public safe_bool<A>
{
   // operator bool() const { return true; }
   operator bool_type() const { return to_bool_type(true); }
};
```

The only addition to existing base classes would be `to_bool_type`, but I hope I've got everything else correct, too.

The test cases I used (VC9) [can be found here](http://www.codeproject.com/tips/51859/reusable-safe_bool-implementation.aspx).

The downsides I see in implementation: `bool_type` and `to_bool_type` are visible in derived classes, which might not appease to everyone. Also, using the wrong template argument (e.g. `class B : public safe_bool<A>` introduced during copy-and-paste) will go unnoticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pointer to a member function as the bool alias is idiomatic, as you're doing here.

Your implementation looks correct for what is there, but slightly incomplete. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool

IMO safe_bool falls into the category of things which do more harm than good; ie the complexity and confusion introduced by this idiom along with the mental effort needed to understand it are greater than the intial problem it is intending to solve.

Comment: Thanks - this the link is actually where I started. I have a few doubts about their implementation, which is why I don't trust every iota there. what seems missing is preventing `operator==(safe_bool<T>)`- but in which case this would be necessary?  
  
---- I'd agree with the complexity vs. usefulness rating, my attempt was to make it "hurt less".

Comment: Downvoting because safe_bool “just works,” especially if you wrap it up in a nicely documented, reusable component.  That said, in C++11 just use an `explicit operator bool() const` and be done with it :-)

Answer (score 4):

The “wrong template argument” problem you mentioned is almost completely eliminated by the `static_cast` in the wikibooks.org solution (“for testability without virtual functions”) cited by @Terry Mahaffey.  The only thing I can see wrong with their solution is the separate `safe_bool_base` class, which will suppress the empty base optimization when it appears in multiple base classes (or elements in a `compressed_pair`).  Personally, I'd move that implementation back up into the template.